# Ruby 1.8.7 RegExp doesn't work with meta-character "\h"

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

If I run this in a 1.8.7 console:

```
$ irb-ruby-1.8.7-p330
1.8.7 :001 > "0a" =~ /\h\h/
 => nil
```

And if I run the same in a 1.9.2 console:

```
$ irb-ruby-1.9.2-p290
1.9.2p290 :001 > "0a" =~ /\h\h/
 => 0
```

:/

Comment: I've never seen `\h` before. What's it supposed to do?

Comment: @RyanBigg http://ruby.runpaint.org/regexps#escapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that `\h` doesn't seem to be recognised by the standard Ruby 1.8.7 regexp library. This can be confirmed using [Rubular](http://rubular.com/). If you need 1.8 compatibility in your code without using any additional gems I think your only alternative is to use an equivalent character class `[0-9a-fA-F]`.